# Why does a value type act like a reference type when it's property of a reference type?

Tags: c#, .net

Why does this:

```
public class BoolClass
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BoolClass bc1 = new BoolClass { Value = false };
        BoolClass bc2 = bc1;
        bc1.Value = true;
    }
}
```

result in

```
bc2.Value == true
```

As `bool` is a value type I would have expected `bc2.Value == false` unless `bc2.Value` is boxed and stored on the heap.

I've found this method on Stack Overflow to tell if the value is boxed

```
public static bool IsBoxed<T>(T value)
{
    return 
        (typeof(T).IsInterface || typeof(T) == typeof(object)) &&
        value != null &&
        value.GetType().IsValueType;
}
```

But it says it's not boxed. I'm somewhat confused now, can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: `bc1` and `bc2` refer to the same object. Try making `BoolClass` a struct.

Comment: You didn't created new Instance just initialized existing so its referring to some object..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is only one instance of `BoolClass` in your `Main` - the one created with

```
BoolClass bc1 = new BoolClass { Value = false }
```

The second variable `bc2` refers to the same exact instance of `BoolClass`, along with all properties attached to that instance. This is because reference types do not get copied.

[image: OneInstance]

Therefore, there is only one `Value` property, and it belongs to the `BoolClass` instance. Any manipulations with that property will be seen through both references to the instance.

Comment: So basically, when a value type is property of a reference type, said property will also be stored on the heap and behave like a reference type and doesn't need to be boxed?

Comment: @Gess Exactly. Essentially, boxing is an act of nesting a value inside a reference object specifically designed to store values of that kind.

Comment: @Gess No, dasblinkenlight is simply wrong.  When a value type is a property of a reference type it doesn't suddenly make it a reference type.  It's still a value type, and it still behaves exactly like a value type.  `bc1.Value` doesn't contain a reference that refers to some value elsewhere, it contains the actual value itself, because it's a value type.  If you copy the value out it copies the actual boolean value, not a reference to some value elsewhere (which is what a reference type would do).

Comment: @Gess Servy misread your comment. The answer to your question is "yes."

Comment: @Servy Gess is talking about a value-typed property inside an object of reference type. It does get stored on the heap, along with the rest of the object's data.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, the value is stored in the heap.  That doesn't make it behave like a reference type, or mean that it is a reference type.  It's a value typed stored in an object that is a reference type, and behaves as such.  That does *not* result in the same semantics as it being a reference type.  The reference type *that it is stored in* is a reference type, and behaves as such.  The value inside it is a value, and behaves as such.  Claiming that storing a value inside of a referenced object *makes it a reference type* is false, as can be easily seen by copying out the boolean value.

Comment: I'm aware the bool is not a reference type just because it is in the heap in this case. However, assigning it a value through `bc1.Value` and then retrieving the newly set value through `bc2.Value`, how is that not reference-type like behavior?

Comment: @Servy I read OP's comment about property's behavior in the context of the object in which it is embedded. As long as a value property remains embedded inside a reference type, the property behaves like a property of a reference type, even though the property itself is value type. OP's last comment above shows that he clearly understands what's going on.

Comment: @Gess `BoolClass` is a reference type.  It behaves like a reference type, because it is a reference type.  You can have two variables that both refer to the same instance of the class, and when you resolve those references to their values, you get the same value, because that's how reference types work.  The boolean value stored within that object, however, does not have that behavior.  It is not a reference. If you assign its value somewhere else, you have copied *a value*, not a reference, and so there won't be two references to a single object, and changes to one won't affect the other.

Comment: @Servy I think you and OP are in violent agreement.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, the property does behave like a property of a reference type, because that's what it is.  It doesn't make the value behave like a reference type, because that's *not* what it is.  The behavior seen is the behavior of *the containing object*, not the behavior of the contained object, and the OP is incorrectly conflating the two, and you're validating that incorrect assumption.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Telling someone that they understand something when they've demonstrated that they don't is *extremely* harmful.  The OP's statements have demonstrated an incomplete understanding of the concepts in a situation where the specifics *matter*, and that's just going to lead to greater confusion down the road when the OP writes other code that results in the value behaving like a value type (because that's what it is) instead of a reference type.

Comment: Ok, I see that assigning said value-type from the heap to another value-type is indeed an operation of value-type behavior. Maybe I've phrased it poorly above. Considering the above example maybe it's better to say _it just looks like the value-type is behaving like a reference-type because of its enclosing (parent) reference-type._

Comment: @Gess No it's not better to say that. It doesn't look like it behaves like a reference-type at all. It's just a value-type that's a field of an Object. Imagine your `Main` had a local variable `bool value2 = false` and then you assign `true` to it and you check if `value2` is `true` and it is! Is that a surprising and/or reference-type like behavior? The exact same thing happens in the example you gave in your question only with a field instead of with a local variable.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're creating only one instance of BoolClass (the line with 'new' in it). When assigning bc2, you're assigning it the same object reference as bc1, so they now point to the same object.

So, when assigning bc1.Value, you're changing the boolean on the same object as bc2 and therefore, it also contains the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't created new Instance just initialized existing so its referring to some object.
If you create new using `new` then it will refer to different object.Ex-

```
  BoolClass bc1 = new BoolClass { Value = false };
  BoolClass bc2 = new BoolClass();
  bc2.Value = bc1.Value
  bc1.Value = true;
```

Now `bc2.Value` will be false only

Answer (score 0):

Because you created an instance of BooClass:

```
BoolClass bc1 = new BoolClass { Value = false };
```

And then affect this object reference to an other object reference bc2 :

```
BoolClass bc2 = bc1;
```

Therefore bc2 and bc1 point now the same BooClass instance.